# how to find the element using index method from a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

im working with a log file containing data. I converted the text file into a list using python, i would now like to print out the user that are mentioned in the file by using the index() method.

```
file = open("live.txt", 'r')
result = [line.split(' ') for line in file.readlines()]
result.index(10)
```

I know that the user is mention in element number 10 from the list, but for some reason i dont get the username printed out.

Comment: "ValueError: '10' is not in list" is the error message that i'm getting

Comment: ...Are you looking for `result[10]`?

Comment: `string.split` returns a list, meaning that `result` is going to be a list of lists.  Maybe define it like `result = [x for line in file.readlines() for x in line.split(' ')]`

Comment: Good luck with debugging.

Comment: remember index's start at `0` so the tenth element is actually index `9`

Comment: one line of the file looks like this:                                                                Sep 15 04:34:02 li146-252 sshd[12130]: Failed password for invalid user ronda from 212.58.111.170 port 41130 ssh2 . which i have put into a list seperated by spaces so it looks like this: ['Sep', '15', '04:34:28', 'li146-252', 'sshd[13324]:', 'Failed', 'password', 'for', 'invalid', 'user', 'ronda', 'from', '212.58.111.170', 'port', '42454', 'ssh2\n']. What i want is to print out every user from the this lis using the index() method in python, the user is on possition 10 ("ronda" is a user)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an element from a list and you know its index, don't use the `index` method, use a subscript (A.K.A. square brackets).

```
>>> file = open("live.txt", 'r')
>>> result = [line.split(' ') for line in file.readlines()]
>>> print(result[10])
['Hello,', "I'm", 'the', 'text', 'that', 'lives', 'on', 'the', 'eleventh', 'line', 'of', 'live.txt']
```